# PCIe slot detected by dmidecode but not by lspci

Tags: linux, motherboard, pci-express

I'm using a computer with 4 different PCI slots. I'm using a x4 lanes PCIe device in one of them (a x4 lanes slot), and it works properly. However,  I haven't managed to make it work in the x16 lanes. First I thought that the OS didn't recognize the device, but now I think it's a problem with the PCI slot by itself: when I use sudo dmidecode | grep "PCI" it lists all the PCIe slots, but when I do sudo lspci | grep "PCI" it only shows 3 out of three slots, lacking the x16 slot (see below the outputs). I'm using CENTOS 7. Is there any way to activate the x16 PCIe slot, so I can use it with my device as I do with the x4 PCIe slot? When I connect the device to the x16 slot, it is well powered (LED blinks as they do when connecting to x4 lanes PCIe).

Thanks!

PS. The device I try to use is a FPGA powerd by PCIe

```
$sudo dmidecode | grep "PCI"
        PCI is supported
    Designation: Slot1 / X16PCIEXP
    Type: x16 PCI Express 3 x16
    Designation: Slot2 / X1PCIEXP1
    Type: x1 PCI Express 2 x1
    Designation: Slot3 / X1PCIEXP2
    Type: x1 PCI Express 2 x1
    Designation: Slot4 / X4PCIEXP
    Type: x4 PCI Express 2 x4
HP BIOS iSCSI NIC PCI and MAC Information
    NIC 1: PCI device 01:00.3, MAC address 00:02:01:00:00:00
    NIC 2: PCI device 00:00.2, MAC address 00:00:00:BA:00:03
HP BIOS iSCSI NIC PCI and MAC Information
    NIC 1: PCI device 01:00.3, MAC address 00:02:01:00:00:00
    NIC 2: PCI device 00:00.2, MAC address 0B:00:00:05:00:03
HP BIOS iSCSI NIC PCI and MAC Information
    NIC 1: PCI device 01:01.1, MAC address 00:02:01:00:00:00
    NIC 2: PCI device 03:00.2, MAC address FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:04
    NIC 3: PCI device ff:00.0, MAC address FF:FF:31:00:05:00
    NIC 8: PCI device 0a:00.0, MAC address 00:34:00:00:00:00
HP BIOS iSCSI NIC PCI and MAC Information
    NIC 1: PCI device 01:00.7, MAC address 00:02:01:00:00:00
    NIC 2: PCI device 00:00.2, MAC address 02:01:00:00:00:03
    NIC 3: PCI device 02:00.0, MAC address 01:00:00:00:04:05
    NIC 6: PCI device 07:1f.7, MAC address 00:08:00:FF:FF:FF

$ sudo lspci | grep "PCI"
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
```

EDIT: outputs of more commands:

```
$ lspci -nm
00:00.0 "0600" "8086" "191f" -r07 "103c" "8053"
00:02.0 "0300" "8086" "1912" -r06 "103c" "8053"
00:14.0 "0c03" "8086" "a12f" -r31 -p30 "103c" "8053"
00:14.2 "1180" "8086" "a131" -r31 "103c" "8053"
00:16.0 "0780" "8086" "a13a" -r31 "103c" "8053"
00:16.3 "0700" "8086" "a13d" -r31 -p02 "103c" "8053"
00:17.0 "0106" "8086" "a102" -r31 -p01 "103c" "8053"
00:1c.0 "0604" "8086" "a115" -rf1 "" ""
00:1c.6 "0604" "8086" "a116" -rf1 "" ""
00:1d.0 "0604" "8086" "a118" -rf1 "" ""
00:1f.0 "0601" "8086" "a146" -r31 "103c" "8053"
00:1f.2 "0580" "8086" "a121" -r31 "103c" "8053"
00:1f.3 "0403" "8086" "a170" -r31 "103c" "8053"
00:1f.4 "0c05" "8086" "a123" -r31 "103c" "8053"
00:1f.6 "0200" "8086" "15b7" -r31 "103c" "8053"


$ lspci -t
-[0000:00]-+-00.0
           +-02.0
           +-14.0
           +-14.2
           +-16.0
           +-16.3
           +-17.0
           +-1c.0-[01]--
           +-1c.6-[02]--
           +-1d.0-[03]--
           +-1f.0
           +-1f.2
           +-1f.3
           +-1f.4
           \-1f.6


$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:191f] (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 [8086:1912] (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [8086:a131] (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 [8086:a13a] (rev 31)
00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H KT Redirection [8086:a13d] (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a102] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:a115] (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 [8086:a116] (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:a118] (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [8086:a146] (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC [8086:a121] (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus [8086:a123] (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [8086:15b7] (rev 31)
03:00.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Xilinx Corporation Device [10ee:7024]
```

Comment: What board are you using? Why do you want to run it in the x16 slot?

Comment: It's an FPGA board called XPressK7, I want to use several ones in the same motherboard so I need to use the x4 lane slot and the x16 lane slot

Comment: Well it was more in regards to the motherboard itself. Some board do require additional configuration for other slots. Some might switch to 8x/8x if you have a graphics card and so on.

Comment: Please edit question with full output of `lspci -nn` and `lspci -t`. `dmidecode` just lists the BIOS tables, which can have little relevance to what the OS is actually doing. Also note that x16 slot is `PCIe 3` instead of `PCIe 2`, so possibly you need a driver for a second host controller. Look into `dmesg` if you see anything suspicious.

Comment: I have tried different mother boards and the same has happened: HP CZC62196DM  in an Elite Desk800G2TWR, an HP CZC23645PJ motherboard in a HP Compaq Elite 8300 Microtower and also in an ASUS motherboard (but I don't have the model available anymore). I'm beginner with this so I don't know how to change the configuration of the PCIe slots if needed. I have only checked in the BIOS if the slots were available and they are.

Comment: `lspci -t` clearly shows only 3 bridges, so only 3 slots. (BTW, I meant `lspci -nn`, not `lspci -nm`, but I can deal with that, too). I'd have expected something like `00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 07)` for the x16 slot. If you tried the different motherboards with the same CentOS harddisk, first thing I'd do is to make sure you have the newest kernel with the newest drivers. Next thing is to look at `dmesg` if the `00:01.0` device (or similar) is ignored for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I have run  lspci -nn and dmesg and it seems it ignores the x16 PCIe slot, I post the lspci output in the main post, the other is too long but it doesn't show any information about this slot